# Search engine spider don't support my site's encoding

Tags: character-encoding, web-crawler, joomla3.0

Ok this is my last hope to find a solution. I have a site, built with joomla 3.0, which contains greek characters for the most part. The content is displayed properly with any browser, and I have installed correctly the greek langouage at root/language/el-GR.
I want to make some seo actions, so I found this site [webconfig.com](http://www.webconfs.com/search-engine-spider-simulator.php), which have a search engine spider simulator, I typed my site's url and this is how it looks in search engines' perspective:

> Spidered Text : Home ΞΞ½Ξ±ΞΆΞ�ΟΞ·ΟΞ·... ViΞ»a SuΞΌΞΌer! ΞΞ±
>   ΞΌΞ΅Ξ―Ξ½Ξ΅ΞΉΟ ΞΊΞΉ Ξ΅ΟΟ ΟΞ΅ ΞΞ―Ξ»Ξ±! HomeΞΞ―Ξ΄Ξ·
>   ΞΞΉΞ±ΞΊΞΏΟΟΞ½ΞΞ½Ξ±Ξ»Ξ»Ξ±ΞΊΟΞΉΞΊΞ­Ο ΞΞΉΞ±ΞΊΞΏΟΞ­ΟΞΞ³ΟΞΉΞ±
>   Ξ¦ΟΟΞ·Ξ§Ξ±Ξ»Ξ¬ΟΟΟΞ·ΞΞ΅ΟΞ¬Ξ½ΟΟΞΌΞ±Ξ£ΟΞ΅ΟΞΉΞΊΞ¬ ΞΌΞ΅
>   Ξ΅ΞΌΞ¬ΟΞ ΞΏΞΉΞΏΞΉ
>   Ξ΅Ξ―ΞΌΞ±ΟΟΞ΅ΞΟΞΉΞΊΞΏΞΉΞ½ΟΞ½Ξ―Ξ±Ξ₯ΟΞ·ΟΞ΅ΟΞ―Ξ΅ΟΞ
>   Ξ±ΟΞΏΟΞ­ΟΞΟΞ¬ΟΞ·ΟΞ·Ξ£ΟΞ½Ξ΄Ξ΅ΟΞ· ΟΟΞ�ΟΟΞ· Home  Ξ ΞΉΞΏ
>   Ξ΄Ξ·ΞΌΞΏΟΞΉΞ»Ξ� Ξ¬ΟΞΈΟΞ± Ξ ΞΞΉΞ³ΞΉΞ±Ξ»ΟΟ Ξ€ΞΏ ΞΊΟΞ�ΞΌΞ± Verve
>   KΟΞ�ΞΌΞ±ΟΞ± Ξarie ΞΞ±ΟΞΌΞ¬ΟΞΉΞ± Ξ½Ξ΅ΟΟΟΞΉΟΟΞ· Ξ²Ξ―Ξ»Ξ±
>   ΞΞ»Ξ­Ξ½Ξ· Daphnis Villas ΞΞ±ΟΞΌΞ¬ΟΞΉΞ± Ξ½Ξ΅ΟΟΟΞΉΟΟΞ· Ξ²Ξ―Ξ»Ξ±
>   ΞΞ»Ξ­Ξ½Ξ· Ξ ΞΈΞ±ΟΞΌΞ¬ΟΞΉΞ± Ξ½Ξ΅ΟΟΟΞΉΟΟΞ· Ξ²Ξ―Ξ»Ξ± ΞΞ»Ξ­Ξ½Ξ·,
>   Ξ΅Ξ―Ξ½Ξ±ΞΉ ΟΟΞΉΟΞΌΞ­Ξ½Ξ· 300ΞΌ Ξ±ΟΟ ΟΞ·Ξ½ ΟΞ±ΟΞ±Ξ»Ξ―Ξ± ΞΊΞ±ΞΉ
>   Ξ±ΟΞΏΟΞ΅Ξ»Ξ΅Ξ―ΟΞ±ΞΉ Ξ±ΟΟ 5 ΞΊΟΞ΅Ξ²Ξ±ΟΞΏΞΊΞ¬ΞΌΞ±ΟΞ΅Ο Ξ£ΟΞΏΞ½
>   Ξ΅ΟΞ¬Ξ½Ο ΟΟΞΏΟΞΏ Ξ΅Ξ―Ξ½Ξ±ΞΉ Ξ· ΞΊΟΟΞΉΞ± Ξ΄ΞΉΟΞ»Ξ�
>   ΞΊΟΞ΅Ξ²Ξ±ΟΞΏΞΊΞ¬ΞΌΞ±ΟΞ± ΞΌΞ΅ ΟΞΏ ΟΞ±ΟΞ¬ΞΈΟΟΞΏ ΟΞ·Ο ΞΊΞ±ΞΉ
>   ΟΞΏ Ξ±Ξ½ΞΏΞΉΟΟΟ ΟΞΆΞ±ΞΊΞΏΟΞΆΞΉ ΟΞ·Ο Ξ½Ξ± Ξ²Ξ»Ξ­ΟΞ΅ΞΉ ΟΞΏ
>   Ξ±ΟΞ­ΟΞ±Ξ½ΟΞΏ Ξ³Ξ±Ξ»Ξ¬ΞΆΞΉΞΏ ΞΊΞ±ΞΉ ΟΞΏ Ξ·Ξ»ΞΉΞΏΞ²Ξ±ΟΞ―Ξ»Ξ΅ΞΌΞ±.
>   ΞΞΉΞ±Ξ²Ξ¬ΟΟΞ΅ ΟΞ΅ΟΞΉΟΟΟΟΞ΅ΟΞ±: ΞΞ±ΟΞΌΞ¬ΟΞΉΞ±
>   Ξ½Ξ΅ΟΟΟΞΉΟΟΞ· Ξ²Ξ―Ξ»Ξ± ΞΞ»Ξ­Ξ½Ξ· KΟΞ�ΞΌΞ±ΟΞ± Ξarie Ξ
>   ΞΌΞ­ΟΞ± ΞΌΟΞΏΟΞ΅Ξ― Ξ½Ξ± ΞΎΞ΅ΞΊΞΉΞ½Ξ�ΟΞ΅ΞΉ ΞΌΞ΅ Ξ­Ξ½Ξ±
>   ΟΞ»ΞΏΟΟΞΉΞΏ ΟΟΟΞΉΞ½Ο ΟΟΞΏ ΞΊΞ±ΟΞ΅Ξ½Ξ΅Ξ―ΞΏ ΟΞΏΟ
>   ΞΊΟΞ�ΞΌΞ±ΟΞΏΟ Ξarie ΟΞ±ΟΞ­Ξ± ΞΌΞ΅ ΟΞ·Ξ½ Ξ±Ξ½Ξ±ΟΞΏΞ»Ξ� ΟΞΏΟ
>   Ξ·Ξ»Ξ―ΞΏΟ. ΞΞΉΞ±Ξ²Ξ¬ΟΟΞ΅ ΟΞ΅ΟΞΉΟΟΟΟΞ΅ΟΞ±: KΟΞ�ΞΌΞ±ΟΞ±
>   Ξarie Daphnis Villas Ξ£ΟΞ·Ξ½ ΞΟΞ�ΟΞ·, ΟΟΞΏΞ½ Ξ ΟΟΞ³ΞΏ
>   Ξ¨Ξ·Ξ»ΞΏΞ½Ξ­ΟΞΏΟ ΟΞΏΟ Ξ Ξ»Ξ±ΟΞ±Ξ½ΞΉΞ¬, 15 ΟΞΉΞ»ΞΉΟΞΌΞ΅ΟΟΞ±
>   Ξ΄ΟΟΞΉΞΊΞ¬ ΟΞ·Ο ΟΟΞ»Ξ·Ο ΟΟΞ½ Ξ§Ξ±Ξ½Ξ―ΟΞ½, ΞΊΞ±ΞΉ ΞΌΟΞ»ΞΉΟ
>   200 ΞΌΞ­ΟΟΞ± Ξ±ΟΟ ΟΞ· ΞΈΞ¬Ξ»Ξ±ΟΟΞ±, Ξ²ΟΞ―ΟΞΊΞ΅ΟΞ±ΞΉ ΟΞΏΒ
>   Daphnis Villas. Ξ§Ξ»ΟΞ·,Β ΞΟΞ»Ξ·,Β Ξ¦Ξ±Ξ―Ξ΄ΟΞ±Β ΞΊΞ±ΞΉΒ
>   ΞΞ±Ξ½Ξ¬Ξ·, ΞΏΞΉ ΟΞ­ΟΟΞ΅ΟΞΉΟΒ Daphnis Villas ΞΞΉΞ±Ξ²Ξ¬ΟΟΞ΅
>   ΟΞ΅ΟΞΉΟΟΟΟΞ΅ΟΞ±: Daphnis Villas La Perla Villas Ξ€ΞΏ
>   ΟΟΞ³ΞΊΟΟΟΞ·ΞΌΞ± La Perla Villas Ξ±ΟΞΏΟΞ΅Ξ»Ξ΅Ξ―ΟΞ±ΞΉ Ξ±ΟΟ
>   ΟΟΟΟΞΊΞ±ΟΞ΅Ο ΞΊΞ±ΟΞΏΞΉΞΊΞ―Ξ΅Ο ΞΊΞ±ΞΉ Ξ½Ξ΅ΟΞΊΟΞΉΟΟΞ΅Ο
>   Ξ²Ξ―Ξ»Ξ΅Ο ΟΟΞ·Ξ½ ΞΊΞ±ΟΞ΄ΞΉΞ¬ ΟΞ·Ο ΞΞ±Ξ»Ξ½ΟΞ­ΟΞ±Ο. Ξ
>   ΟΟΞΊΞ΅ΞΉΟΞ±ΞΉ Ξ³ΞΉΞ± Ξ­Ξ½Ξ± ΞΎΞ΅Ξ½ΞΏΞ΄ΞΏΟΞ΅Ξ―ΞΏ ΟΞΏΟ Ξ­ΟΞ΅ΞΉ
>   ΟΞ±ΟΞ±ΞΊΟΞ·ΟΞΉΟΟΞ΅Ξ― ΟΟ Β«ΞΞΉΞ±ΟΞ·ΟΞ·ΟΞ­ΞΏΒ» ΞΊΞ±ΞΉ
>   ΟΟΞΏΟΟΞ±ΟΞ΅ΟΞ΅ΟΞ±ΞΉ Ξ±ΟΟ ΟΞΏΞ½ ΞΞΈΞ½ΞΉΞΊΟ
>   ΞΟΞ³Ξ±Ξ½ΞΉΟΞΌΟ Ξ€ΞΏΟΟΞΉΟΞΌΞΏΟ (Ξ.Ξ.Ξ€). ΞΞΉΞ±Ξ²Ξ¬ΟΟΞ΅
>   ΟΞ΅ΟΞΉΟΟΟΟΞ΅ΟΞ±: La Perla Villas (c) 2012 by Maria Petriti,
>   Santarita Simoni. All Rights Reserved. HomeΞΞ―Ξ΄Ξ·
>   ΞΞΉΞ±ΞΊΞΏΟΟΞ½Ξ£ΟΞ΅ΟΞΉΞΊΞ¬ ΞΌΞ΅
>   Ξ΅ΞΌΞ¬ΟΞ₯ΟΞ·ΟΞ΅ΟΞ―Ξ΅ΟΞ£ΟΞ½Ξ΄Ξ΅ΟΞ· ΟΟΞ�ΟΟΞ· Joomla Template
>   by Joomla51.com

I tried to add a meta http-equiv tag with the greek encoding right before the "jdoc:include" tag at my template's index.php but with no avail

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php   echo $this->language; ?>" >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-7">
<jdoc:include type="head" />
```

I also tried a core hack to manualy change the utf-8 with iso-8859-7 in libraries/joomla/factory.php, which I know is not a good practice. The result was that the browser could not recognize the greek charactes as before but the simulator still gave the same outcome as before, so I changed back to utf-8.

Here's the site's url
http://www.vilasummer.eu/

Can you please help?

Comment: For all that we can know from the data disclosed, it could be just the simulator that has difficulties with the encoding. You could post the URL of your page so that we could check whether the encoding is properly declared in HTTP headers or at least so that there is no conflict between them and the actual encoding. On the other hand, UTF-8 is safest. From the description, it is not clear what you are doing and what you actually tried (you wrote that you “changed back to utf-8”).

Comment: I tested another site with greek encoding with the same simulator and the result was correctly encoded text. I also added the site url at the end of the question. I changed back to utf-8 because somehow iso-8859-7 messed up even the greek characters that the browser displayed correctly before.